# ¿Como obtengo un elemento por un atributo?

Tags: javascript

quisiera obtener este elemento

```
<span data-offset-key="4lpif-0-0">
<span data-text="true">Texto</span>
</span>
```

lo que quiero es que obtenga el tag

```
<span data-offset-key="4lpif-0-0"></span>
```

osea para luego cambiarle lo de adentro con innerHTML

¿Es posible con JS puro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer utilizando `document.querySelector` y selectas el primer elemento que tiene un atributo `data-offset-key` cuyo valor es `4lpif-0-0`

```js
let elSpan = document.querySelector("[data-offset-key = '4lpif-0-0']");
elSpan.innerHTML = "lo que fuera"
```

```html
<span data-offset-key="4lpif-0-0"></span>
```